# Webcam keeps getting disconnected (Error code: 0xA00F4289 and 0xA00F4244)

Tags: windows-10, webcam

I'd like to ask regarding the problem that I have with my webcam. After I switch on my webcam, after some time, it will keep turned off and on, and when it's off, it seems that my webcam was not detected.

Attached are the videos (converted to GIF), one is produced using Zoom meeting, and other one is from the Windows camera app.

Using Zoom

[image]

If you see from the image above, the webcam icon will keep disappearing (signs of the webcam is disconnected). Therefore the video was turned off.

Using Windows 10 camera app

[image]

Similar to Zoom, the screenshot showed the message that it can't find the camera.
The error message

We can't find your camera

> 1. 
>
> Check to make sure that it's connected and installed properly, that it
> isn't being blocked by anti-virus software, and that your camera
> drivers are up to date.
>
> If you need it, here's the error code:
>
> 0xA00F4289 (0xC00D3EA2)
>
> 2.
> We can't find your camera
>
> Check to make sure that it's connected and installed properly, that it
> isn't being blocked by anti-virus software, and that your camera
> drivers are up to date.
>
> If you need it, here's the error code:
>
> 0xA00F4244

Device as stated in device manager is BisonCam, NB Pro. I tried to update the driver but Windows said that the best drivers are already installed.

Windows Version : 10.0.19042.630

Is this a software issue or hardware issue?

Comment: When I had this issue, or a very similar issue, it was caused by a OEM USB driver.

Comment: My webcam is internal webcam in the laptop, not a USB plugged webcam.

Comment: @Ramhound I have done that but it did not solve the issue.